# How can I connect database(Microsoft SQL server 2012) with Mathematica?

Tags: sql-server, wolfram-mathematica

I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and created new database, some new tables &  also inserted some values into that table.

I want to access that data from Mathematica. I read documentation about `OpenSqlConnection[]`and `JDBC[]` but didn not get it. I didn't create any drivers in my system.

I installed database in my system & I want to connect database with Mathematica.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my recommendation:

1. Bring in the DatabaseLink package:

Needs["DatabaseLink`"];

1. Open a connection to the database:

conn = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)", "/"], "Username" -> "", "Password" -> ""];

1. Start using the database.  Here is an example query on table "Names"

bunchOfNames = SQLSelect[conn, {"Names"}]

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I have a doubt in your code.
you mentioned like `conn=OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)","/"],"Username"->"","Password"-> ""];`

I didn't understood `"/"` this part in your code.what it means?

for that,I seen documentation,documentation defines that part is `URL`.url means where I installed `SQL Server`.this one or anything else ?

I hope you understand,what my doubt is?

Answer (score 1):

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]

//SQL Security
conn = OpenSQLConnection[
  JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)", "serverName:1433/"], 
  "Username" -> "domain\username", "Password" -> "1234", 
  "Catalog" -> "MathematicaTestDB", "instance" -> "I2"]  

//Windows Integrated
conn = OpenSQLConnection[
  JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)", "serverName:1433/"],      
  "Catalog" -> "MathematicaTestDB", "instance" -> "Instance2"]    
  d1 =  SQLExecute[conn, "SELECT * FROM DUMMYDATA"]
```

For the Windows Integrated you need to [download the jTDS dist](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/1.3.0/jtds-1.3.0-dist.zip/download), extract out the ntlmauth.dll file. jTDS must be able to load the native SPPI library (ntlmauth.dll). Place this DLL anywhere in the system path (defined by the PATH system variable) and you're all set.

Comment: Does the trick for SQL Server with (Windows) Integrated Authentication.  Thanks.